# D3.js SVG object not showing every time I run react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have created a basic `D3 svg` just to test some things out with react. For reference, here is my code:

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Graph from './Graph/Graph';

function App() {
  return (
    <Graph />
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Graph.js**

```
import * as d3 from "d3"

function Graph(props) {
    let svg = d3.select("svg")

    svg.append('rect')
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .style("fill", "Green");
    
    return (
        <div>
            <svg id="svgID" width="640" height="480"></svg>
            <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </div>
    )
  }

export default Graph
```

The issue I am having is where it loads the green rectangle only sometimes, I don't seem to have control over when it loads and when it doesn't.

I think it might be because the `SVG` is being returned before it has time to append anything to it, however, I am unsure of a fix. Any help?

Comment: You can't mutate the DOM without telling to React, you need to use `useRef`

Comment: @Jerboas86 could you explain further?

Comment: Why you have script tag in `Graph` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a reference of your `svg` DOM element which persists between renders. The React API gives you the `useRef` to do that with functional component [(see docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

To bind a DOM Element with a reference, you need to use the ref JSX arrtibute.

```
<svg ref={svgRef} id="svgID" width="640" height="480"></svg>
```

Since useRef doesn't tell when it is binded with the DOM element, you need to couple the "ref" returned with `useEffect` hook to check when current is binded with the `svg` DOM element.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import * as d3 from "d3"

function Graph(props) {
    const svgRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(
        () => {
             // Check that svg element has been rendered
             if(svg.current) {
                 let svg = d3.select(svgRef.current)

                 svg.append('rect')
                 .attr("height", 10)
                 .attr("width", 10)
                 .style("fill", "Green");
            }
        }

},[svgRef.current])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <svg ref={svgRef} id="svgID" width="640" height="480"></svg>
        </div>
    )
  }

export default Graph
```